# margin auto not centering content

Tags: css, html, containers, center, margin

Hello so I'm having an issue with simple CSS.  I'm attempting to get my div tag centered on my page by using margin-right: auto and margin-left: auto, but it doesn't seem to be centering the content.  I've searched for answers, but I cannot find anything wrong with the simplest bit of code.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#container {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-color: #666;
    height: auto;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
Hello world!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The div is centered for me. The text however, within it isn't.

Comment: There must be an issue with my browser rendering my css.  Thanks j

Comment: What browsers do you use? Isn't it IE? Without doctype, any IE renders the page as IE5, which didn't support centering with `margin:auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:table` to your #container

```
#container {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-color: #666;
    height: auto;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only reason that it may not centre for you is that you have no

```
<DOCTYPE html>
```

and so the page load equivalent to ie5, which does not support

```
margin: 0 auto;
```